# GWT multiple Paging (Best / easiest way)

Tags: java, gwt, pagination

So far I've done some tests (e.g RPC)
Next I come to the Part Multiple Paging, in what I've read so far there are so many options for this:

MVP, Layout, UIbind.

Now I really don't know which I should choose, which is easy and good.

I tried clearing my Rootpanel and placing another Widget(composite):

```
    RootPanel.get().clear();
```

Place:

```
    LoginComp login = new LoginComp();
    rootPanel.add(login, 127, 125);
```

I don't know if this is the most professional approach. What is the best way to include my widgets as composites?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, GWT is a single page application. After you have requested the application, you'll only go to the server to recieve data.

I would use a struts or SpringMVC application for the logon and request the GWT application after a successfull login. Your GWT application should have a shell. This shell has an area where you can change your views. Changing a view is initiated via a place controller.

Take a look at the mobileWebApp example contained in the GWT SDK examples.

Also, you will find a good documentation here:

[MVP and Places Documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)

Comment: I agree with this answer. If you're not using a MVP layout, you can just use the [GWT History mechanism](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html). It works by adding a hash `#page_name` at the end of your webapp URL, along with a handler. So your app is still running in the same page, but the Back and Forward buttons on the browser respond to #page changes. This behavior can be seen when you use the links in the "Contents" section  [any Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion, the best way is when you add a element in your main HTML file which acts like a content wrapper e.g.

```
 <div id="content"></div>
```

Each of your page can be represented as extended `Panel`, simultaneously as a singleton. The page that should be display will be set into that wrapper:

```
 RootPanel.get("content").set(pagePanelX);
```